# Register generic interface without access to implementation

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac, factory

We have abstracted the usage of NLog behind a facade and a factory. Our factory returns an instance of our NLogFacade, which more or less wraps an NLog logger. We have our own interface for both the factory and the logger facade, so we can register them via DI and mock them in testing. The factory has a generic and non-generic method for creating an `ILogger` and the `ILogger` interface exists in a non-generic and a generic flavor.

### ILogFactory

```
public interface ILogFactory
{
    ILogger GetLogger(string name);

    ILogger GetLogger<TCallingType>();
}
```

### ILogger of T

```
public interface ILogger<TOwner> : ILogger { }
```

### ILogger

```
public interface ILogger
{
    // This is set as typeof(T).FullName if ILogger<T> is used
    // or if ILogFactory.GetLogger<T>() is used.
    string Name { get; }

    void Trace(string message, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "");
    void Info(string message, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "");
    void Error(string message, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "");
    void Error(string message, Exception exception, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "");
    void Error(Exception exception, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "");
    void Fatal(string message, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "");
    void Fatal(string message, Exception exception, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "");
    void Fatal(Exception exception, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "");
    void Log(LogLevel level, string message, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "");
    void Log(LogLevel level, string message, Exception exception, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "");
}
```

Currently, I'm registering our log factory using autofac, and injecting it into my constructors.

```
builder.Register(context => LogService.GetInstance().LogFactory).As<ILogFactory>();
```

I don't have access to the implementation for either `ILogFactory` or `ILogger`. They are both internal classes to the company assembly that has our logging stuff in it.

What I would like to do is register `ILogger<T>` to be injected.

```
// Pseudo Registration
builder.Register(context => LogService.GetLogger<>).As<ILogger<>>();

// Construtor
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger) { }
```

Is there a way for me to do that, or get access to the Type that my service is being injected into? I can use a non-generic call to get a logger, where i pass the logger name and register a non-generic `ILogger`. In order to use that, I'd need to know the Type the service is being injected into. Something like this:

```
builder.Register(context => LogService.GetLogger(context.ResolvingType.FullName))
    .As<ILogger>();
```

When I look at the `Register` method on the `ContainerBuilder`, I don't see anything that would let me determine the Type the service is being injected into. I've also looked at `OnActivating` and `OnActivated` which doesn't have any of the Type information I need either. Is there a way for me to determine the Type the service is going into? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

To register open generics, you can't use a generic type ref parameter because those need to be resolved at compile time. You have to pass the open generic as a `Type` argument to the method, not a type ref parameter.

```
builder.Register(context => LogService.GetLogger(typeof(Logger<>))).As(typeof(ILogger<>));
```

Which of course means you need to change your factory design to:

```
public interface ILogFactory
{
    ILogger GetLogger(string name);

    ILogger GetLogger<TCallingType>(); // Maybe you won't actually need this overload...

    ILogger GetLogger(Type type);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve this without changing the API on the factory.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using a Module ([as explained in their docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html)) to resolve the `ILogger` when it is being injected as a parameter into a constructor. The `Preparing` event lets me peek into the parameters, and find out what the owning type is for the parameter my service is being injected as.

```
internal class LoggingDependencyRegistrationModule : Autofac.Module
{
    private static void OnComponentPreparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(new[]
        {
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger),
                (p, i) => LogService.GetLogger(p.Member.DeclaringType.FullName)),
        });
    }

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        // Handle constructor parameters.
        registration.Preparing += OnComponentPreparing;
    }
}
```

Then in my DI setup I register the module.

```
builder.RegisterModule(new LoggingDependencyRegistrationModule());
```

And finally I can inject the logger into my constructor

```
public HomeController(ILogger logger)
{
    // This correctly equals MyNamespace.Controllers.HomeController.
    string controllerName = logger.Name;
}
```